# Emacs ECB - Saving and Restoring a Custom Layout

Tags: layout, emacs, emacs-ecb

In emacs with ecb running as a minor mode, I would like to set my layout as default. So once emacs starts, I go drag the pane on the left side to change my layout and when I say "Store current window sizes" under "Layout administration" it does correctly write to a file `~/.gnu-emacs-custom`. But then when I start emacs again, the default window sizes are back and I have to drag the pane again. However when I do `M-x ecb-restore-window-sizes` the sizes are set correctly.

So, somehow the default sizes get set. Adding this line at the end of my .emacs file makes it work `(run-with-idle-timer 0.2 nil 'ecb-restore-window-sizes)` but I don't like it this way, it should be working by default.

Any help would be appreciated.

UPDATE:
I am not very experienced with debugging emacs, but following [wvxvw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/797257/wvxvw)'s suggestion below, I found the definition of `ecb-restore-window-size` and inserted `(debug)` into it.
Then I ran emacs with the `--debug-init` option and got the following output:
`Debugger entered: nil

ecb-restore-window-sizes()

(progn (ecb-restore-window-sizes))

<and a lot of other lines which I believe are statements fired when ecb-restore-window-sizes is referenced>`
I think this means that the function runs during init and there are no deaths, right?

Answer (score 1):

in your init, try this

(add-hook 'ecb-mode-hook 'ecb-restore-window-sizes)

Comment: sorry about the delay for a feedback. Unfortunately adding `ecb-restore-window-sizes` as a hook as you described above did not work.